# A number-theory question on the deficiency function $2x - \sigma(x)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, conjectures, divisor-sum

Let $\sigma(x)$ be the sum of the divisors of a (positive) integer $x$.  (For example, $\sigma(2) = 1 + 2 = 3$.)

Define the [deficiency](http://oeis.org/A033879) function $D(x)$ to be the number
$$D(x) = 2x - \sigma(x).$$

Let $y$ be a (positive) integer.  Now I compute the difference:
$$D(xy) - D(x)D(y) = 2xy - \sigma(xy) - (2x - \sigma(x))(2y - \sigma(y))$$
$$=2xy - \sigma(xy) - 4xy + 2y\sigma(x) + 2x\sigma(y) - \sigma(x)\sigma(y)$$
$$=-2xy - 2\sigma(x)\sigma(y) + 2y\sigma(x) + 2x\sigma(y) + (\sigma(x)\sigma(y) - \sigma(xy))$$
$$=2(x - \sigma(x))(\sigma(y) - y) + (\sigma(x)\sigma(y) - \sigma(xy)).$$

This is because I want to compare $D(xy)$ and $D(x)D(y)$.  Note that, in general we have
$$2(x - \sigma(x))(\sigma(y) - y) \leq 0$$
and
$$\sigma(x)\sigma(y) - \sigma(xy) \geq 0.$$

Lastly, observe that if we have $D(xy) = D(x)D(y)$, then it follows that
$$2(\sigma(x) - x)(\sigma(y) - y) = \sigma(x)\sigma(y) - \sigma(xy).$$

My question is:  Will it be possible to prove either
$$D(xy) \leq D(x)D(y)$$
or
$$D(x)D(y) \leq D(xy),$$
subject to additional assumptions, if necessary?

[Updated Sept. 8, 2015]

> If $x$ and $y$ are relatively prime (i.e., $\gcd(x, y) = 1$), then it follows that $D(xy) \leq D(x)D(y)$.  By the contrapositive, we have the equivalent implication: "If $D(x)D(y) < D(xy)$, then $\gcd(x, y) > 1$."

Finally, I conjecture that if the equation $D(xy) = D(x)D(y)$ is true, then either $x$ or $y$ is $1$, or both $x$ and $y$ are powers of $2$.

Comment: I am not particularly sure if the preliminary results in this [paper](http://www.rjpa.info/index.php/rjpa/article/view/292/215) would be of any help in trying to obtain what I want in this MSE post.

Comment: @MrSelberg, so are you saying that $D(2x) = D(2)D(x)$ (where $x$ is odd) is true in general?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your line of reasoning, @MrSelberg.  If $\gcd(2,x)=1$, then $D(2x) = 2(2x) - \sigma(2x) = 4x - 3\sigma(x)$, which may not be equal to $D(2)D(x) = 2x - \sigma(x)$ in general.  Equating, $4x - 3\sigma(x) = 2x - \sigma(x)$ gives $2\sigma(x)=2x$, from which we obtain $\sigma(x) = x$.  Finally, we have $x = 1$.

Comment: Sorry, I see a mistake in my computations, I took, $\sigma$ as the **number** of divisor, but you want the **sum**. My bad.

Comment: To cite a specific example:  The deficiency of $2\cdot{73}$ is $D(2\cdot{73}) = 4\cdot{73} - \sigma(2\cdot{73}) = 292 - 222 = 70$, which isn't equal to $D(2)D(73) = 1\cdot(146 - 74) = 72$.

Comment: That's fine, @MrSelberg!  My profuse thanks for your taking the time out to leave a comment in this MSE question of mine.  =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran some quick numerics to see what sort of things happen.

You have two questions. Firstly, you conjecture

> $D(xy) = D(x)D(y) \implies x$ or $y = 1$, or both $x,y$ are powers of $2$.

I have no intuition for whether this should or shouldn't be true. But the smallest counterexample I found was $15$ and $3$. Note that $D(15) = 30 - (1 + 3 + 5 + 15) = 6$ and $D(3) = 6 - (1 + 3) = 2$. On the other hand, $D(45) = 90 - (1 + 3 + 5 + 9 + 15 + 45) = 12$.

So $D(45) = D(3)D(15)$, and this conjecture is false.

Secondly, you consider the inequalities

> Can we say that $D(xy) \geq D(x)D(y)$ or $D(xy) \leq D(x)D(y)$ in a meaningful way?

After the raw numerics, it seems that $D(xy) < D(x)D(y)$ more often. We might expect this, as we know that
$$ \sum_{n \leq X} \sigma(n) = \frac{\zeta(2)}{2}X^2 + O(X),$$
leading to the (very loose) heuristic that the average value of $\sigma(n)$ is about $n\zeta(2)/2$. But $D(xy) > D(x)D(y)$ very often, with few discernible patterns (at first glance). It will take (perhaps many or specific) additional constraints to say when either inequality holds.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comprehensive answer, @mixedmath!  I appreciate it.  =)

Comment: A scenario that I can think of whereby $D(xy) \leq D(x)D(y)$ is when $x$ and $y$ are relatively prime.