# A follow-up number-theory question on the deficiency function $D(x) = 2x - \sigma(x)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisor-sum, multiplicative-function

This question is a follow-up to these previous posts: [MSE1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1426061) and [MSE2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1426344).

Let $x, y$ be positive integers.  We call $\sigma(x)$ the sum of the divisors of $x$.

Let the deficiency function $D(x)$ be defined by
$$D(x) = 2x - \sigma(x).$$

Now here is my question:

> If $x \mid y$, does it follow that $D(xy) = D(x)D(y)$? If the implication does not hold in general, what additional assumptions on $x, y \in \mathbb{N}$ must be made in order for the equation to hold?

So for example, take $x = 2$ and $y = 4$, so that:
$$D(8) = 1 = 1\cdot1 = D(2)D(4).$$

If I take $x = 3$ and $y = 9$, then
$$D(27) = 14 = 2\cdot7 \neq 2\cdot5 = D(3)D(9).$$

If $x = 3$ and $y = 15$, we get
$$D(45) = 12 = 2\cdot6 = D(3)D(15).$$

Lastly, if $x = 3$ and $y = 21$, we obtain
$$D(63) = 22 = 2\cdot{11} \neq 2\cdot{10} = D(3)D(21).$$

Comments are most welcome.  Thanks!

**Added February 13 2017**

It turns out we may say something about $x$, $y$, $D(x)$, and $D(y)$ when $x \mid y$.

If $x \mid y$, then by a property of the *abundancy index* $I(z)=\sigma(z)/z$, we have
$$I(x) \leq I(y)$$
$$2 - I(y) \leq 2 - I(x)$$
$$\dfrac{2y-\sigma(y)}{y} \leq \dfrac{2x-\sigma(x)}{x}$$
$$\dfrac{D(y)}{y} \leq \dfrac{D(x)}{x}.$$

Additionally, note that we have $x^2 \mid xy \mid y^2$ if $x \mid y$, so that
$$I(x^2) \leq I(xy) \leq I(y^2)$$
$$2 - I(y^2) \leq 2 - I(xy) \leq 2 - I(x^2)$$
$$\dfrac{2y^2 - \sigma(y^2)}{y^2} \leq \dfrac{2xy - \sigma(xy)}{xy} \leq \dfrac{2x^2 -\sigma(x^2)}{x^2}$$
$$\dfrac{D(y^2)}{y^2} \leq \dfrac{D(xy)}{xy} \leq \dfrac{D(x^2)}{x^2}.$$

**I am *tempted* to call the ratio $D(z)/z$ as the *deficiency index*, moving forward!**

Comment: It seems that, if $x \mid y$, then $D(xy) \geq D(x)D(y)$ (might need to further assume that both $x$ and $y$ are deficient).

Comment: No. For $x=2,y=10$, we have $D(xy)\lt D(x)D(y)$ where both $x$ and $y$ are deficient.  It can be proven that there are infinitely many pairs $(x,y)$ such that $x\mid y$ and $D(xy)\not=D(x)D(y)$.

Comment: Would you mind fleshing out the last sentence in your comment, into an actual answer (preferably, with both $x$ and $y$ deficient), so that I may be able to accept it?  Thanks, @mathlove!  =)

Comment: Just to double-check your last comment:  For $x = 2, y = 10$, I have
$$D(xy) = D(20) = 2(20) - \sigma(20) = 40 - \sigma(2^2)\sigma(5) = 40 - {7}\cdot{6} = 40 - 42 = -2$$
and
$$D(x) = D(2) = 2(2) - \sigma(2) = 4 - 3 = 1,$$
$$D(y) = D(10) = 2(10) - \sigma(2)\sigma(5) = 20 - {3}\cdot{6} = 20 - 18 = 2,$$
so that we indeed obtain
$$D(xy) = -2 < 2 = D(x)D(y).$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems that, if $x\mid y$, then $D(xy)\ge D(x)D(y)$ (might need to further assume that both $x$ and $y$ are deficient).

No. A counterexample is $(x,y)=(2,10)$ where
$$D(xy)=-2\lt 2=D(x)D(y)$$
$$\sigma(x)=3\lt 4=2x\qquad\text{and}\qquad \sigma(y)=18\lt 20=2y$$

---

**Claim** : There are infinitely many pairs $(x,y)$ such that $x\mid y$ and $D(xy)\lt D(x)D(y)$ where both $x$ and $y$ are deficient.

Proof :

Let $x=2,y=2p$ where $p\ge 5$ is an odd prime. Then, we get
$$\begin{align}D(xy)&=D(4p)=8p-\sigma(4p)=8p-(1+2+2^2)(1+p)=p-7
\\\\D(x)D(y)&=(4-\sigma(2))(4p-\sigma(2p))=(4-3)(4p-(1+2)(1+p))=p-3\end{align}$$
with$$2x-\sigma(x)=4-3=1\gt 0\qquad\text{and}\qquad 2y-\sigma(y)=4p-3(1+p)=p-3\gt 0$$

It follows that
$$D(xy)\lt D(x)D(y),\qquad \sigma(x)\lt 2x,\qquad \sigma(y)\lt 2y.\qquad\square$$

Comment: What a terrific proof!  I honestly did not see that coming, @mathlove!  +1!  =)