# Can these bounds, for the deficiency $D(x)=2x-\sigma(x)$ of a deficient number $x>1$, be improved?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, divisor-sum

Let $\sigma=\sigma_{1}$ denote the classical sum-of-divisors function.  Denote the *deficiency* of the deficient number $x>1$ by $D(x)=2x-\sigma(x)$.

Since $x>1$ is deficient, we have $D(x) \geq 1$. (Note that $D(x) \neq 0$ since deficient numbers *cannot* be [perfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number).)

Additionally, since $\sigma(x) \geq x+1$ for all $x>1$, it follows that $D(x)=2x-\sigma(x) \leq x-1$.

Thus, we have the bounds
$$1 \leq D(x)=2x-\sigma(x) \leq x-1.$$

Here is my question:

> **Can these bounds be improved?**

**Added July 26 2016**

There is a related MSE question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1426061), where it is shown that the deficiency function $D(w)=2w-\sigma(w)$ satisfies
$$D(xy) \leq D(x)D(y)$$
whenever $\gcd(x,y)=1$.

**Added August 27 2016**

I have a newer (and related) MSE question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1904757).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they cannot be improved. In particular, there are infinitely many $x$ with $D(x) = 1$ and infinitely many with $D(x) = x-1$. For example, if $x = 2^{k}$, then $\sigma(x) = 2^{k+1} - 1$ and so $D(x) = 1$. On the other hand, if $x$ is prime, then $D(x) = 2x - (x+1) = x-1$.