# What is a sharp upper bound for $\prod_{i=1}^{r}{\left({p_i}^{\alpha_i} - \sigma({p_i}^{\alpha_i - 1})\right)}?$

Tags: inequality, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions

What is a sharp upper bound for $$\prod_{i=1}^{r}{\left({p_i}^{\alpha_i} - \sigma({p_i}^{\alpha_i - 1})\right)}?$$

Here, the $p_i$'s are primes, and $\sigma = \sigma_1$ is the classical sum-of-divisors function.  You may assume that
$$X = \prod_{i=1}^{r}{{p_i}^{\alpha_i}},$$
and that $r = \omega(X)$ is the number of *distinct* prime factors of $X$.

(Note: This question is related to this [earlier MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1871566).)

Comment: are you kidding ? $\sigma(p^{a-1}) = \frac{p^{a}-1}{p-1} = p^{a-1} + \mathcal{O}(p^{a-2})$

Comment: No, I am not kidding @user1952009.  I suggest you re-evaluate your computation.  =)

Comment: If I got correctly what you meant to ask, let me clarify that I want an upper bound for the product in terms of $X$.

Comment: you can't write $\sigma(p^{a-1})$ for $\frac{p^a-1}{p-1} = p^{a-1} + \frac{p^{a-1}-1}{p-1}$

Comment: What can't I?
$$\sigma(p^{a-1})=1+p+\ldots+p^{a-1}=\dfrac{p^{(a-1)+1} - 1}{p - 1},$$
right?

Comment: because it becomes obvious : $\prod_{i < r} p_i^{a_i} (1-p_i^{-1}+\mathcal{O}(p_i^{-2}))$

Comment: So are you saying that the product is less than $X$?  But of course it is!  What I am asking for is a sharper upper bound.  If you have one, I invite you to write out your comments as an actual answer, so that I may be able to accept it if needs be.

Comment: $\phi(n) = n \prod_{p | n} (1-p^{-1})$

Comment: Okay, I see now.  I suggest you write that down as an actual answer.  Thanks, @user1952009!  =)

Comment: I suggest you writing $\frac{p^a-1}{p-1}$ instead of $\sigma(p^{a-1})$ next time, and read some number theory course

Comment: can you write an answer now ?

Comment: Yes, I think so.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking cue from [user1952009](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/276986)'s comments, we have
$$\prod_{i=1}^{r}{\left({p_i}^{\alpha_i} - \sigma({p_i}^{\alpha_i - 1})\right)} = \prod_{i=1}^{r}{\left({p_i}^{\alpha_i} - \frac{{p_i}^{\alpha_i} - 1}{p_i - 1}\right)}.$$

Since
$$\frac{p^{\alpha} - 1}{p - 1} = p^{\alpha - 1} + \mathcal{O}(p^{\alpha - 2})$$
we obtain
$$\prod_{i=1}^{r}{\left({p_i}^{\alpha_i} - \frac{{p_i}^{\alpha_i} - 1}{p_i - 1}\right)} = \prod_{i=1}^{r}{\left({p_i}^{\alpha_i} - {p_i}^{\alpha_i - 1} - \mathcal{O}({p_i}^{\alpha_i - 2})\right)} = \prod_{i=1}^{r}{{{p_i}^{\alpha_i}}\cdot\left(1 - {p_i}^{-1} - \mathcal{O}({p_i}^{- 2})\right)}.$$

This last quantity is bounded by
$$\prod_{i=1}^{r}{{{p_i}^{\alpha_i}}\cdot\left(1 - {p_i}^{-1} - \mathcal{O}({p_i}^{- 2})\right)} \leq \prod_{i=1}^{r}{{{p_i}^{\alpha_i}}\cdot\left(1 - {p_i}^{-1}\right)} = \phi(X).$$

Hence, we have the relation
$$D(X) \leq \prod_{i=1}^{r}{\left({p_i}^{\alpha_i} - \sigma({p_i}^{\alpha_i - 1})\right)} \leq \phi(X),$$
where $D(X)=2X-\sigma(X)$ is the [*deficiency*](http://oeis.org/A033879) of $X$.

Comment: In which sense is this bound "sharp"?

Comment: It is "sharp" in the sense that the bound is "in terms" of $X$.  (It will suit my purposes).  Of course, there may well be other *sharper* upper bounds.