# If $D(x)=2x-\sigma(x)$, then if $n>1$ is deficient which is bigger, $D(n)$ or $D(n^2)$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, inequality, divisor-sum

(In what follows, we let $\sigma(x)$ denote the sum of the divisors of $x \in \mathbb{N}$.  $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$ is the abundancy index of $x$, while $D(x)=2x-\sigma(x)$ is the deficiency of $x$.)

From this [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1426061), I have the equation
$$D(xy) - D(x)D(y) = 2xy - \sigma(xy) - (2x - \sigma(x))(2y - \sigma(y))$$
$$=2xy - \sigma(xy) - 4xy + 2y\sigma(x) + 2x\sigma(y) - \sigma(x)\sigma(y)$$
$$=-2xy - 2\sigma(x)\sigma(y) + 2y\sigma(x) + 2x\sigma(y) + (\sigma(x)\sigma(y) - \sigma(xy))$$
$$=2(x - \sigma(x))(\sigma(y) - y) + (\sigma(x)\sigma(y) - \sigma(xy)).$$

Note that, in general we have
$$2(x - \sigma(x))(\sigma(y) - y) \leq 0$$
and
$$\sigma(x)\sigma(y) - \sigma(xy) \geq 0.$$

Thus, we obtain:

> **Proposition:** If $x$ and $y$ are relatively prime (i.e., $\gcd(x, y) = 1$), then it follows that $D(xy) \leq D(x)D(y)$.

Note that we cannot apply the preceding result to our present problem:

**PROBLEM STATEMENT**

> If $D(x)=2x-\sigma(x)$, then if $n>1$ is deficient which is bigger, $D(n)$ or $D(n^2)$?

Nonetheless, note that we have the following partial result:

**MY ATTEMPT**

Since $n>1$, we obtain
$$\sqrt{I(n^2)}<I(n)<I(n^2),$$
and
$$I(n)=2-\frac{D(n)}{n}$$
$$I(n^2)=2-\frac{D(n^2)}{n^2}.$$
It follows that $D(n^2)<nD(n)$, and
$$\sqrt{2-\frac{D(n^2)}{n^2}}<2-\frac{D(n)}{n}<2-\frac{D(n^2)}{n^2}.$$
Consequently, 
$$2-\frac{D(n)}{n}<2-\frac{D(n^2)}{n^2}<\bigg(2-\frac{D(n)}{n}\bigg)^2.$$
Since $n>1$ is deficient, then
$$1<2-\frac{D(n)}{n}<\bigg(2-\frac{D(n)}{n}\bigg)^2$$
so that
$$0<\bigg(2-\frac{D(n)}{n}\bigg)\bigg(1-\frac{D(n)}{n}\bigg)$$
whence it follows that
$$0<1-\frac{D(n)}{n}$$
which implies that
$$D(n)<n.$$
Consequently,
$$D(n^2)<nD(n)<n^2.$$
Alas, this is where I get stuck.

Comment: it look like the past few question are related and never answered, why not try MW instead of MSE ? (+1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result depends on $n$.

For example
$$D(3^k)=\frac{3^k+1}{2}<\frac{3^{2k}+1}{2}=D(3^{2k}),$$
$$D(2^k)=1=D(2^{2k}).$$
And for any prime $p\in(2^{k+1},2^{2k+1})$, we have
$$D(2^kp)=p+1-2^{k+1}>0>1+(p-2^{2k+1})(p+1)=D(2^{2k}p^2).$$
All three families give infinitely many instances.

Also, I'd like to note a fact that $D(494)=148>11=D(494^2)$, which is an instance of $D(n)>D(n^2)>0$. However, I have no idea whether there are other instances.

**EDIT:** More $n$ with the property $D(n)>D(n^2)>0$:
\begin{align}
&2\cdot13\cdot19\cdot44371\\
&2\cdot13\cdot19\cdot44381\\
&2\cdot13\cdot19\cdot44383\\
&2\cdot13\cdot19\cdot44371\cdot2406128687\\
&2\cdot13\cdot19\cdot44371\cdot2406128689\\
&2\cdot13\cdot19\cdot44371\cdot2406128687\cdot2466259112360839463\\
\end{align}
To get this list, I just make use the known instances of $D(n)>D(n^2)>0$ and multiply it with an appropriate prime $p$ such that $D(np)>D(n^2p^2)>0$. I believe we may obtain more instances by relax the constrains.