# An inequality for the sum-of-aliquot-divisors function

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, upper-lower-bounds, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions

> **In what follows, we shall assume that $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime.  (That is, $\gcd(a,b)=1$ holds.)**

It is known that the inequality
$$\sigma(ab) \leq \sigma(a)\sigma(b)$$
holds for the *sum-of-divisors* function $\sigma(x)$.

It is also [straightforward to show](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1426061) that the inequality
$$D(ab) \leq D(a)D(b)$$
holds for the *deficiency* function $D(x)=2x-\sigma(x)$.

Here is an attempt towards proving that the corresponding inequality
$$s(a)s(b) \leq s(ab)$$
holds for the *sum-of-aliquot-divisors* function $s(x)=\sigma(x)-x$:

> $$s(ab)=\sigma(ab)-ab=\sigma(a)\sigma(b)-ab$$
> $$s(a)=\sigma(a)-a$$
> $$s(b)=\sigma(b)-b$$
> $$s(a)s(b)-s(ab)=(\sigma(a)-a)(\sigma(b)-b)-(\sigma(a)\sigma(b)-ab)$$
> $$=\sigma(a)\sigma(b)-a\sigma(b)-b\sigma(a)+ab-\sigma(a)\sigma(b)+ab$$
> $$=2ab-a\sigma(b)-b\sigma(a)=(ab-b\sigma(a))+(ab-a\sigma(b))$$
> $$=b(a-\sigma(a))+a(b-\sigma(b)) \leq 0,$$

where the last inequality holds since $x \leq \sigma(x)$ for all integers $x \geq 1$.

This completes the proof.

**An Improvement to the Inequality When it is Known that $a > 1$ and $b > 1$**

We have the penultimate equation and improved inequality:

> $$s(a)s(b)-s(ab)=b(a-\sigma(a))+a(b-\sigma(b)) \leq -b - a = -(a+b),$$

where we have used the estimate $\sigma(x) \geq x + 1$, which holds for all integers $x>1$.

**QUESTIONS**

> **(1)** Is the derivation of the improved inequality correct?
>
> **(2)** Will it be possible to derive a better bound than the improved inequality?  Or is this already best-possible?

Comment: As I've written in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3601883/78967), we get $\sigma(m^2)\ge m^2+6m+19$. The inequalities Wlod AA wrote are nice, but I guess that you want to have an inequality only about $m$.

Comment: Thank you for your application of Wlod AA's results to that other question of mine, @mathlove!  =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(1)** Looks **good** to me.

**(2)** The inequality cannot be simply improved since it is sharp when $\ a\ b\ $ are different primes.

However, inequality can be made more subtle and in this way -- indeed -- it can be *improved*. For instance (a not very systematic list of special cases follows):

- **If** relatively prime integers $\ a\ b\ $ are such $\ a>1\ $ and $\ b\ $ is composite then $\ \sigma(a)\ge a+1\ $ and $\ \sigma(b)\ge b+3$ hence

$$ \sigma(a\cdot b)\ \ge
      \ a\cdot b\ +\ (3\cdot(a+1)\ +\ b) $$

- **If** relatively prime integers $\ a\ b\ $ are both composite then
  $$ \sigma(a\cdot b)\ \ge\ (a+\sqrt a+1)\cdot(b+\sqrt b+1) $$

so that for $\ a<b\ $ we get

$$ \sigma(a\cdot b)\ \ge\ (a+3)\cdot(b+4)\,\ =\,\ a\cdot b
 \ +\ (3\cdot(a+b)\ +\ a\ +\ 12) $$

- **If** $\ a>1\ $ and $\ b:= p^x\cdot q^y\cdot t\ $ where $\ p\ q\ $
  are different primes and $\ m:=\min(x\ y).\ $ Then the worst case is for $\ a:=5,\ p:=2,\ q:=3\ $ and $\ t:=1.\ $ Then

$$ \sigma(a\cdot b)\ \ge \sigma(5)\cdot\sigma(2^2)\cdot\sigma(3^2)\ =
        \ 6\cdot 7\cdot 13\ =\ 546 $$
or more generally we get the worst case when $\ p<q<a\ $ and $\ t:=1;\ $
then

$$ \sigma(a\cdot b)\ \ge\ (a+1)\cdot m^2\cdot(p^2+p+1)\cdot(q^2+q+1) $$

The obtained expression is so much larger than $\ a\cdot\ b\ $ that comparing them doesn't seem interesting (unless there are some special requirements).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @WlodAA!  I am actually considering the case when $a$ is a prime or prime power, and $b$ is a composite.  =)

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebita-Dris, a prime power with exponent $\ >\ 1\ $ is considered composite. Perhaps you mean that $\ b\ $ has more than two prime divisors. This would make/imply a stronger inequality than above since then $\ \sigma(b)\ \ge\ b+6\ $ or even, still better: $\ \sigma(b)\ \ge\ b +\lceil2\cdot\sqrt b\rceil+1.$

Comment: Thank you for your time and attention, @WlodAA.  I am considering the case
$$ab = {p^k}{m^2}$$
where $a = p^k$ and $b = m^2$.  Here, $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ (so far, I cannot rule out $k=1$), and $m$ is a composite.

Comment: Then $\ a=3\ $ and $\ b=16\ $ is the worst case; or do you mean than $\ m\ $ has at least two different prime divisors? Then $\ a=5\ $ and $\ b=36\ $ would be the worst case.

Comment: I mean that $m$ has at least two different prime divisors, yes.  Can you please update your answer @WlodAA, so that I may be able to accept it?  Thanks a bunch!  =)

Comment: Thank you for your updated answer, @WlodAA!  Gladly accepting it now.  =)

Comment: My pleasure and honor. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**(1)** It looks correct to me.

**(2)** You cannot get a better inequality than
$$s(a)s(b)-s(ab)\leq -(a+b)$$
since the equality of this inequality holds when $a,b$ are distinct primes.

Comment: Thanks, @mathlove!  =)