# An improved inequality for the deficiency function when $\gcd(x,y)=1$, $x > 1$, and $y > 1$

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, upper-lower-bounds, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions

(The following is an attempt to improve on the result contained in this [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1426061).)

Let $\sigma(x)$ be the sum of the divisors of a (positive) integer $x$.  (For example, $\sigma(2) = 1 + 2 = 3$.)

Define the [deficiency](http://oeis.org/A033879) function $D(x)$ to be the number
$$D(x) = 2x - \sigma(x).$$

Let $y$ be a (positive) integer.  Now I compute the difference:
$$D(xy) - D(x)D(y) = 2xy - \sigma(xy) - (2x - \sigma(x))(2y - \sigma(y))$$
$$=2xy - \sigma(xy) - 4xy + 2y\sigma(x) + 2x\sigma(y) - \sigma(x)\sigma(y)$$
$$=-2xy - 2\sigma(x)\sigma(y) + 2y\sigma(x) + 2x\sigma(y) + (\sigma(x)\sigma(y) - \sigma(xy))$$
$$=2(x - \sigma(x))(\sigma(y) - y) + (\sigma(x)\sigma(y) - \sigma(xy)).$$

Now, assuming that $\gcd(x,y)=1$, the second term vanishes, and we are left with
$$D(x)D(y) - D(xy) = 2(\sigma(x) - x)(\sigma(y) - y).$$
If we further assume that $x>1$ and $y>1$ both hold, then we have
$$\sigma(x) - x \geq 1$$
$$\sigma(y) - y \geq 1$$
from which it follows that
$$D(x)D(y) - D(xy) \geq 2\times{1}\times{1} = 2.$$
We therefore conclude that
$$D(x)D(y) \geq D(xy) + 2.$$

Here are my questions:

**QUESTIONS**

> **(1)** Is the derivation of the improved inequality correct?
>
> **(2)** Will it be possible to derive a better bound than the improved inequality?  Or is this already best-possible?

Comment: **(1)** It looks correct to me. **(2)** You cannot get a better inequality than $D(x)D(y) - D(xy) \ge 2$ since the equality of this inequality holds when $a,b$ are distinct primes. (If you have some other conditions on $x,y$, then please write them in the question.)

Comment: Thank you for your time and attention, @mathlove!  I know of no other conditions for $x$ and $y$.  Kindly write out your last comment as an actual answer so that I may be able to accept it.  Thank you!  =)

Comment: I've just converted my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(1)** It looks correct to me.

**(2)** You cannot get a better inequality than
$$D(x)D(y) - D(xy) \ge 2$$
since the equality of this inequality holds when $a,b$ are distinct primes.